# Classical Guitar stringing and tuning

Tags: guitar, classical-music

I am going to record a new songs and to be well prepared I changed my strings, the way I stretch them is to set them and wind them two step higher than normal E strings to sol#note A ti do# and etc... and keep this position for 24 hours by rewinding them again and again whenever I could, did I damaged them, I checked the 12 fret and discoverd that they do not excactly match the free string tune, should I change the strings before recording, my guitar is COMPAS classic and the strings are DADARIO EJ45. I have not checked the 12 fret before on this guitar, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

By just leaving the strings tighter than they should be for a day or two isn't going to bed them in. The main problem point is where they wrap around the post on the machine head. Also the bridge, where the strings are tied on a classical guitar. At those points, the strings are pulling against themselves. The better way is to get each up to pitch, then pull along the length. I don't pull like a bow, but rather stretch out a hand and push with thumb, pull with ring finger, along the length of each string. This needs doing (on all guitars) several times, until the tuning of each string settles. Often, the next day, they still need a little strtch before tuning stability is attained.

To make life easier, you only need two or three wraps around the posts, making sure the string isn't over itself. Although, the unwrapped strings can sometimes be stopped from slipping by doing just that. And, not so obvious, wrap it the right way- left or right!

The 12th fret issue is probably one that pre-existed, unless you've used different gauge strings. It's the intonation of the guitar, and on a classical, often can't easily be remedied, as the bridge is fixed.There are loads of Q&A on this site referring to this problem, but with a classical guitar it's best left to a luthier.

Comment: Thank you it was really helpful, I am still trying to understand what does #strings are pulling against themselves# mean as you see I am not a native English speaker, but do you mean there is no nees to change the strings they could not be damaged or they did damaged because the #strings are pulling against themselves# problem, again thank you very much....

Comment: I stongly advice against tuning strings sharp as this can cause problems with tension on the bridge and is generally a bad idea. Tune them to the right note and stretch with fingers, then repeat. @Tim did a good job of explaining this, +1

Comment: After 50 yrs of restringing guitars of all kinds, a semitone or two will not cause a properly mounted bridge problems. And it's a temporary extra tension for a short while anyway. What I mean is a string may be wrapped around the post, and on the second wrap, it lies over itself.

Comment: I also worry about the strings, I mean did this temporary tension or overwinding affect the intonation of the strings?*two steps means for semitones I guess*

Comment: It's possible, but in my opinion, doubtful.A tone above isn't drastic for 24 hrs, usually.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again you are really helping me but I want to say something, it is not one tone it is two tones e.g the E strings to sol# the A string to do# sometimes one and a half...

Comment: A to doh# is 2 tones, and it's too much! Do as I suggest and it'll be fine.

Comment: does the damage occur gradually to the overtuned strings? in this case I will record with them for a while, but next time will follow you steps, is it ok?

Comment: If they sound and feel good, all the same, and are keeping in tune, go for it!

Comment: Thank you a lot I know I am annoying, yes they sound and feel good, but I remember one of the strings I guess D or A gave some wheeze like sound when I overwinded it, should  I just ignore that..

Comment: Ignore it if it's o.k. now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I ask a lot about that because I am going to record in my home studio I really appreciate your advice but do you consider that I will record with this strings?

Comment: have you received my last question please this is the last one, I do not throw responsibility on you but just for the peace of mind,,

Comment: It's impossible to give a direct answer - I cannot hear the guitar! But, if you feel that the sound is good from each string, go ahead. If you have any doubts, it's better to purchase a new set of strings, and put them on as indicated. Good luck.